# Postfix button, text not formatted well

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm trying to use the `button postfix` class but I can't quite get the same effect as on the demo page.

I copy-pasted code from http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html into the index.html page that comes with all the css/js.

This is what I expect:

[image: Correct result]

This is what I get:

[image: Incorrect result]

As you can see the Go is all pushed on the right. You should be able to reproduce this by pasting in the index.html page the following markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <div class="row collapse">
      <div class="small-10 columns">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Hex Value">
      </div>
      <div class="small-2 columns">
        <a href="#" class="button postfix">Go</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I replicate the same look?

Edit: here is the relevant JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amencarini/h6sjb8L6/1/

Comment: Please make a JSFiddle with your code

Comment: Added the JSFiddle as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at **[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBSA4/84/)**, you can see that the `button` class that make this effect, by removing this class it work just fine (i dont know why, maybe some css override) :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="small-10 columns">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Hex Value"/>
            </div>
            <div class="small-2 columns">
                <a href="#" class="postfix" style='background-color: #008CBA;color:#FFF'>Go</a>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

You can add some inline css if you want the same color like in my example.

Comment: Ha! The `button` class adds a ton of padding that breaks the layout. Resolved by removing that padding. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.